# Passing inputted text to query parameters via button - flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So, i have an application which let's me display journal articles from google scholar by using SERP API. It has a static_model which i specify the query parameters.

```
class StaticValues {
  const StaticValues._();

  static const String apiUrl = 'https://serpapi.com/search.json';
  static const String apiEngine = 'google_scholar';
  static const String apiKey = 'api_key_value';
  static const String apiKeyword = 'biologi';
  static const String yearFrom = '2015';
  static const String yearTo = '2018';
  static const String apiLang = 'id';
}
```

Said query is then mapped to another file called `query_param.dart`.

```
class  QP {
  const  QP._();

  static Map<String, String> apiQp({
    required String engine,
    required String api_key,
    required String q,
    required String as_ylo,
    required String as_yhi,
    required String hl
    }) => {
     'engine': engine,
     'api_key': api_key,
     'q': q,
     'as_ylo': as_ylo,
     'as_yhi': as_yhi,
     'hl': hl
    };
}
```

This, in return will show the result of said query into a listview via a `getData()` function

```
  Future<List<Journal>?> getData() async {
    final response = await NetworkService.sendRequest(
        requestType: RequestType.get, 
        url: StaticValues.apiUrl,
      queryParam: QP.apiQp(
        engine: StaticValues.apiEngine,
        api_key: StaticValues.apiKey,
        q: StaticValues.apiKeyword,
        as_ylo: StaticValues.yearFrom,
        as_yhi: StaticValues.yearTo,
        hl: StaticValues.apiLang
        )
    );
```

Now the thing is, i want to have a text field which the user can input and a submit button will send the query parameters (apiKeyword, yearFrom, and yearTo) to the url. I used getX for the textfield controllers.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.3,
        height: 50,
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
          controller: textControllers.yearFromController.value,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(38),
            vertical: getProportionateScreenWidth(9)),
            hintText: "From",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            ),
        ),
      )
      )
    ),

     SizedBox(
      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.3,
      height: 50,
      child: Center(
        child: TextField(
        controller: textControllers.yearToController.value,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(38),
          vertical: getProportionateScreenWidth(9)),
          hintText: "To",
           border: OutlineInputBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
           borderSide: BorderSide.none,
         ),
        ),
      )
      )
    ),

    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
      }, 
      child: const Text('Search'))
    ]);
  }
```

The question is, how do i return the inputted text on the textfield inside of the query parameter when the user presses the button?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using GetX, you can directly access the entered value by using the controller and wrap the widget with obx.

```
Obx(()=>ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print(textControllers.yearToController.value.text);
                  },
                  child: Text('Search'))),
```

Comment: I think you missed a `'`